# Terraform modules sub directory placement

Tags: terraform

I'm new to terraform and I'm thinking about the best structure for coding new environments.

Let's say I have a root directory for each of my environments dev, staging and production say.

I'm wondering if it's best to locate the modules directory as a child directory off of the root directories or to locate the module directory at that same level as the root directories.

The official guidance shows the modules directory as a child under each root (ie a modules dir for dev, another one for staging etc) but this makes it difficult to share the modules for each environment. This seems to be the official advice though https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/index.html

Where do you usually have internal modules located in your repos?

Regards
Shaun

Answer (score 1):

We try not to create 'internal' modules as they're not reusable across repos, therefore we use the git source rather than the filesystem source. I find this method better because

1. Modules aren't tied to a single repository
2. You can version your modules and [source specific refs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#selecting-a-revision)

When sourcing a module from git, you just create a new repository for each module. Then you can keep things clean with your module files

- main.tf
- variables.tf
- outputs.tf
- versions.tf

Where versions.tf is used for pinning the Terraform core and provider versions required by the module.

i.e.

```
terraform {
    version = "= 0.12.9"
    required_providers {
        aws = ">= 2.7.0"
    }
}
```